# MATLAB smooth function in R

Tags: r, matlab, for-loop, smoothing

I am trying to create MATLAB smooth function code in R.

The following is the calculation for the **function smooth in **MATLAB**** website:

> `yy = smooth(y)` smooths the response data in column vector y using a moving average filter.

> The first few elements of `yy` follow.

```
yy(1) = y(1)
yy(2) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3))/3
yy(3) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5))/5
yy(4) = (y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5) + y(6))/5
...
```

The following is the R code that I have Built:

```
ma <- function(data){
        output <- vector(mode = "double", length = length(data))
        for(i in 1:length(data)){
                for(j in 1:length(output)){
                        if(j == 1){
                                 output[j] <- data[1]
                        } else if(j == 2) {
                                 output[j] <- (data[1] + data[2] + data[3])/3
                        } else if(j >= 3) {
                                output[j] <- (data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2] + data[i + 3] + data[i + 4])/5 
                        } 
                
                }
        }
     output   
}
```

I am using this vector for test:

```
n  = 1000
x  = seq(-pi, pi, length.out = n)

teste <- ma(x)
```

The problem is: it only returns the two first values of the vector. Everything else is `NA`.

Comment: what is `y(1)` or eve `y(2)`? ie what is `y`?

Comment: well in R, `y(1)` means `y` is a function. Sorry. probably you should have written `y[1]` instead but its fine

Comment: what would be `yy(5)` and `yy(10)`??

Comment: But that's the explanation in the MATLAB website, not the R code. It's also informed in the post. https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html

Comment: I did read it. Its only that in R `()` are used to represent a function call and not a subset of a vector

Comment: I know, but that part is the matlab site explanation of the function in matlab. It's not R, it's the MATLAB code that I am trying to transform in R code. That's why it uses () instead of []

Comment: Take a look at the `filter()`  function? It doesn't handle the ends of the series in the same way but it might be good enough ...

Comment: Your `i` loop is meaningless because when you generate the output, you use `j` index as `output[j]`. So at the very last step of your `i` loop, since there is no `i+4` in your data (remember, the length of your data equals `i`), it gives you `NA` as a result. And you assign the `NA` values to the output by using `j` index again.

Comment: I also tried, but I need all the point :( The matlab function computes everything

Comment: In general you should try to make your questions on Stack Overflow as self-contained as possible: whenever possible, people shouldn't have to follow links/go to another site to understand your question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this in R is use `stats::convolve` or use `stats::filter` both work just fine.

```
smooth <- function(y ){
  h <- c(head(y, 1), mean(head(y, 3)))
  t <- c(mean(tail(y, 3)), tail(y, 1))
  m <- stats::convolve(y, rep(1/5, 5), type = "filter")
  c(h, m, t)
}
```

eg:

```
 R> y <- c(5, 3, 7, 10, 4, 9, 12, 2, 1, 5)
 R> smooth(y)
 [1] 5.000000 5.000000 5.800000 6.600000 8.400000 7.400000 5.600000 5.800000
 [9] 2.666667 5.000000
```

MATLAB:

```
 >> y = [5, 3, 7, 10, 4, 9, 12, 2, 1, 5]
 >> smooth(y)

  ans =

      5.0000
      5.0000
      5.8000
      6.6000
      8.4000
      7.4000
      5.6000
      5.8000
      2.6667
      5.0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will study this function to understand how you did that, but this returns the same values!